# why the ThreadLocal only have threadLocalHashcode in Java

Tags: java

Today when I debug my app into `RequestContext` putLoginId method, I found the class static ThreadLocal initial failed, the `contextData.get()` return null, the static contextData only have threadLocalHashCode.

[image]

My `contextData` define in `RequestContext` class like this:

```
public class RequestContext {
    public static final ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> contextData = new ThreadLocal<>();
}
```

the `contextData` should be initialed when load the class, so I think it will never be null. But why this happening and what should I do to fix it? Am I missing something?

Comment: As an aside, storing per-request data such as a login ID in global state (albeit thread-locally, but nonetheless potentially persisted after the request is completed) is not such a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the contextData should be initialed when load the class, so I think it will never be null

`contextData` *is* initialized when the class is loaded; but you don't actually give it a (per-thread) value, at least in the code shown.

---

Give your `ThreadLocal` an initial value with the factory method, for example:

```
public static final ThreadLocal<Map<String, Object>> contextData =
    ThreadLocal.withInitial(HashMap::new);
```